# Помогите с регуляркой PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Т.к. вы любите подробности то с них и начну ;)
Написал человеку сайт. В Админке статьи добавляются с помощью CKEditor с функцией вставить картинку =) Ну и человек постоянно вставляет картинки, иногда лишние... В общем накопилось много мусора в картинках.
Решил написать скрипт с кнопкой в админке, чтобы искала во всех статьях тег `<img src="имя картинки">`, потом сканируем папку images и сравниваем файлы.
Те что в статьи не входят удаляем.
Но регулярные выражения хромают у меня =(

код: `$txt = "text text text text text text <img width="100%" src="имя файла картинки" class="какой то класс"> text text text text text text text "`

```
preg_match_all (найти **ТОЛЬКО** содержимое **SRC**, без кавычек)
```

Помогите написать регулярку.

Comment: 1) подробности мы не любим, мы любим суть 2) HTML-парсер

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1688077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас прибежит @Vlad и будет ругаться за регулярки в отношении HTML.
Но можно так:

```
$txt = 'text text text text text text <img width="100%" src="имя файла картинки" class="какой то класс"> text text text text text <img class="dlsfj" src=\'pathToImg\' />text text ';
preg_match_all('!<img[^>]+src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"]!', $txt, $matches);
```

В `$matches[1]` будут пути.

Comment: Зачем ругаться? Ну хочется человеку забивать гвозди коробкой спичек, ну пускай.

Comment: @VladD, Помнится мне ты голову мылил целый вечер на этот счёт :)

Comment: Я такая противоречивая вся (ц)

Comment: А мою любимую ссылку уже запостили до меня. Реквестирую добавление её в шаблонные комментарии.

Comment: @VladD, Так ты девушка о_О?

Comment: Я Кролик же! :-) А цитата из «Покровских ворот».

Comment: @VladD, Не смотрел ничего кроме "Джентльменов удачи" и подобной классики.

Comment: @ReinRaus, Забытое из теста, сейчас изменим.
Хотел такой фэн-шуй сделать, только не захотел он заработать у меня.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Где ж вы, вопрос про регулярки!

Comment: @VladD, да тут все спокойно :-) Сейчас TheDoctor внесет правки и я поставлю ему плюсик :-)

Comment: @ReinRaus, Может лучше не включать первые скобки в выборку?

Comment: Даже в твоем примете при print_r($matches) выводит Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>

Comment: У меня растянутый скрипт получился. 1) Я из статей в массив сохраняю все теги IMG ($pattern='|<img.*>|Ui';) 2) Потом из этого массива выдергиваю SRC '|src=".*"|Ui' 3) Потом из SRC выдергиваю то что между кавычками '|".*"|Ui'  (выдергивается с кавычками) И тут микросхемы поплавились и я решил возвать к гуру регулярок =)

Comment: @FrancNet, вот поэтому (в том числе, причина не единственная!) и не стоит насиловать мир и себя регекспами, а воспользоваться готовым парсером.

Comment: @TheDoctor, сделал откат назад к правильному ответу, без фэн-шуй. Последняя ревизия была ошибочной.

Comment: @ReinRaus, Похоже я чуть запутался :)
Хотя выложенная с самого начала регулярка работала - я её из тестового скрипта выдрал.

Comment: Спасибо большое, последний вариант заработал =)

Answer (score 3):

Предложу альтернативный вариант с парсером (пушо у нас его всегда рекомендуют, но сам процесс не показывают). Понадобится установленный и подключенный [symfony/dom-crawler](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dom-crawler) и [symfony/css-selector](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/css-selector) (при умении работать с XPath второй необязателен):

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class PostParser
{
    public static function parseImageSources($html)
    {
        $sources = array();
        $crawler = new Crawler($html);
        foreach ($crawler->filter('img') as $node) {
            if ($source = $node->getAttribute('src')) {
                $sources[] = $source;
            }
        }
        return $sources;
    }
}
```

Плюсы:

- Написал буквально на коленке
- Всего-то около десяти строчек, не так страшно, как могло бы быть
- Нет возможности набедокурить с регуляркой

Comment: Ура! Правда заюзать `symfony` для этого...

Comment: @TheDoctor ну вот серьезно. Что стоит за этим аргументом "правда, заюзать Х для этого"? Вы не представляете (и я не представляю) реального быстродействия этой штуки, может, она быстрее регулярок.

Comment: Я не про то. Ставить краулер (в лучшем случае, а то и всю `symfony`) ради того, чтобы выдрать пути - даже не знаю...

Comment: @TheDoctor так а плохого-то что? Я вот прямо для этого ответа поставил, заняло секунд тридцать и чуть больше полмегабайта (и то я не знаю откуда столько, возможно, там сохранена куча HTML для тестов). По сравнению с теми изображениями, которые планируются выцеплять - это вообще ничего.

Comment: @TheDoctor, можно и без symfony - этих парсеров куча.