# Парсер страницы php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, curl, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста простой парсер на php.
Задача очень простая, надо брать с стороннего сайта одну строчку:

```
<img class="png" src="//s3.gismeteo.by/static/images/icons/new/d.sun.png" alt="Ясно" title="Ясно" width="55" height="55">
```

Если в тайтле стоит Ясно, то выводить 1, если облачно, то 2 и так далее. Пытался найти в интерентах, какой-то такой парсер, но что-то не нашел пока. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420108/16095

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    $data_fin = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data_fin;
}
$url = "http://yoursite.com/index.php";
$page = getPage($url);
if(preg_match('/title="Ясно"/',$page)){
    $result = 1;
}else{
    $result=0;
}

echo $result;
```

Код работает при условии установленного модуля curl для php

Comment: Для более точного написания регулярного выражения, напишите линк на страницу которую вы хотите парсить.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net), Luke!
К примеру так:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://your_site.co.uk/');
$data = null;
foreach($html->find('img.png') as $img){
  if(preg_match("/gismeteo\.by/i", $img->href) && $img->width == 55 && $img->height == 55) // Точно идентифицировать изображение нельзя, приходится как-то так
    switch($img->title){
        case "Ясно":
          $data = 1;
        break;
        case "Облачно":
          $data = 2;
        break;
        // Сколь угодно условий
        default:
          $data = 0; // По дефолту
        break;
    }
}
```

Хотя по запросу "Парсер HTML для PHP", выводится огромная куча хорошего и не очень контента с парсерами, как можно пропустить всё..

Answer (score 0):

А как насчет использовать уже готовое?: [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

Answer (score -1):

Пробуйте использовать Регулярные выражения.

```
$str = '<img class="png" src="//s3.gismeteo.by/static/images/icons/new/d.sun.png" alt="Ясно" title="Ясно" width="55" height="55">';
$result = preg_match('/title="Ясно"/',$str);
```

Comment: Если со стороннего сайта то используйте curl для получения удаленной страницы в дополнении к регулярным выражениям. Если вы сами не можете сделать себе парсер, можете обратится к специалистам :)